# Pyodbc SQL INSERT query not working but no error

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sql-insert, commit

In this part of my Python program, I am taking user inputs from Text widgets and inserting them into a pre-existing SQL Server table. The inputs are validated before then being written to the table, however if I try to delete my newly inserted row it is not there. I opened up SQL Server Management Studio and the data doesn't appear to have actually inserted into the table, despite no error when the query was executed.

I'm using Pyodbc, and having already looked around for answers the most common suggestion was to use `conn.commit()` however I already have this in place, and it isn't solving the problem.

My code relevant to this issue is below:

```
        def gsap_commit():

            teams = ["Arsenal", "Aston Villa", "Brentford", "Brighton", "Burnley", "Chelsea", "Crystal Palace", "Everton", "Leeds", "Leicester", "Liverpool",
                      "Man City", "Man United", "Newcastle", "Norwich", "Southampton", "Tottenham", "Watford", "West Ham", "Wolves"]

            gs_fname = gs_ent1.get("1.0", "end-1c")
            gs_sname = gs_ent2.get("1.0", "end-1c")
            gs_apdob = gs_ent3.get("1.0", "end-1c")
            gs_pos = gs_ent4.get("1.0", "end-1c")
            gs_team = gs_ent5.get("1.0", "end-1c")
            gs_price = gs_ent6.get("1.0", "end-1c")
            
            if gs_fname.isalpha() == True and gs_sname.isalpha() == True:
                if int(gs_apdob[5:7]) <= 12 and int(gs_apdob[8:10]) <= 31:
                    if gs_pos == "GK" or gs_pos == "DEF" or gs_pos == "MID" or gs_pos == "FWD":
                        if gs_team in teams:
                            if int(gs_price) > 4.5 and int(gs_price) < 18:
                                addplayerquery = "INSERT INTO PlayerList(FirstName, Surname, DOB, Position, Team, Price, InitialPrice, TotalPts, InjuryStatus, DoubtStatus) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,0,0,0)"
                                cursor.execute(addplayerquery, gs_fname, gs_sname, gs_apdob, gs_pos, gs_team, gs_price, gs_price)
                                conn.commit()
                                tkMessageBox.showinfo("Add Player Successful", "Successfully added player - {0} {1}".format(gs_fname, gs_sname))

                            else:
                                tkMessageBox.showinfo("Add Player Unsuccessful", "The price entered was too anomalous.\nPlease re-enter a suitable price")

                        else:
                            tkMessageBox.showwarning("Add Player Unsuccessful", "Please enter a valid team name")

                    else:
                        tkMessageBox.showwarning("Add Player Unsuccessful", "Please enter a valid position")

                else:
                    tkMessageBox.showwarning("Add Player Unsuccessful", "Please enter a valid birth date")

            else:
                tkMessageBox.showwarning("Add Player Unsuccessful", "Please enter a valid name")


        def gs_add_player():

            gs_ent1.configure(state="normal")
            gs_ent2.configure(state="normal")
            gs_ent3.configure(state="normal")
            gs_ent4.configure(state="normal")
            gs_ent5.configure(state="normal")
            gs_ent6.configure(state="normal")
            gs_ent1.delete("1.0",END)
            gs_ent1.insert("1.0", "First Name")
            gs_ent1.configure(width=20, bd=1)
            gs_ent1.focus()
            gs_ent2.delete("1.0",END)
            gs_ent2.insert("1.0", "Surname")
            gs_ent2.configure(width=20, bd=1)
            gs_ent3.delete("1.0",END)
            gs_ent3.insert("1.0", "DOB ('YYYY-MM-DD')")
            gs_ent3.configure(width=20, bd=1)
            gs_ent4.delete("1.0",END)
            gs_ent4.insert("1.0", "Position")
            gs_ent4.configure(width=8, bd=1)
            gs_ent5.delete("1.0",END)
            gs_ent5.insert("1.0", "Team")
            gs_ent5.configure(width=20, bd=1)
            gs_ent6.delete("1.0",END)
            gs_ent6.insert("1.0", "Price")
            gs_ent6.configure(width=5, bd=1)
            gs_confirm_bt.configure(text="Add", command=gsap_commit)


        gs_addplr_bt = tk.Button(self, text="Add Player", bg="#0ebf08", fg="white", font=("Segoe UI", 12), command=gs_add_player)
        gs_ent1 = tk.Text(self, height=1, width=20, bd=2)
        gs_ent2 = tk.Text(self, height=1, width=20, bd=2)
        gs_ent3 = tk.Text(self, height=1, width=20, bd=2)
        gs_ent4 = tk.Text(self, height=1, width=8, bd=2)
        gs_ent5 = tk.Text(self, height=1, width=20, bd=2)
        gs_ent6 = tk.Text(self, height=1, width=5, bd=2)
        gs_ent1.configure(state="disabled")
        gs_ent2.configure(state="disabled")
        gs_ent3.configure(state="disabled")
        gs_ent4.configure(state="disabled")
        gs_ent5.configure(state="disabled")
        gs_ent6.configure(state="disabled")
        gs_confirm_bt = tk.Button(self, text="Add", fg="white", bg="#38003c", width=10)
        
        gs_addplr_bt.grid(row=6, column=2, columnspan=2, sticky="NSEW", pady=(10,10))
        gs_ent1.grid(row=11, column=0)
        gs_ent2.grid(row=11, column=1)
        gs_ent3.grid(row=11, column=2)
        gs_ent4.grid(row=11, column=3)
        gs_ent5.grid(row=11, column=4)
        gs_ent6.grid(row=11, column=5)
        gs_confirm_bt.grid(row=12, column=2, columnspan=2, pady=(20,0))
```

Here is also the code establishing a connection to SQL Server, declared at the start of the program (different class etc. to code above) in case it is useful:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};"
                      "Server=DESKTOP-MLKS8CG\SQLEXPRESS;"
                      "Database=FFProject;"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;")

cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Could anyone please help me understand why my INSERT statement is not appearing to save? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried passing the param values in as a list, sequence or tuple yet? e.g.: `cursor.execute(addplayerquery, (gs_fname, gs_sname, gs_apdob, gs_pos, gs_team, gs_price, gs_price) )`

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, for me restarting SQL server worked fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).